# Append to default highcharts tooltip

Tags: highcharts, tooltip, linechart

I have a line graph with the y-axis set to category and x-axis to values. On hovering over a point , i get the default tooltip information like in 
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-point-events-mouseover/ when

```
 tooltip: {
        enabled: true
    }
```

My y-axis is set to some label like "Seconds" or "FPS". I want to be able to just add the y-axis label text to the default tooltip without changing any formatting options in the default tootlip, so for example if you hover over the first point it should display **29.9 Seconds** along with the other data keeping other contents unaltered.

I know you can use a formatter and override it but I would like to retain the original tooltip display which shows up when you dont override the formatter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `valueSuffix`, Change your tooltip to this: [Read Here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip)

```
tooltip: {
    enabled: true,
    valueSuffix: ' Seconds',
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/suchit/tb98m39a/1/)

Comment: This is probably the easiest closest solution, can I get the valueSuffix dynamically instead of hardcoding? I want to get the title of y-axis and append it to the value suffix, i've tried this.point.series.yAxis.axisTitle.textStr but it wont work

Comment: Found a way: chart.series[index].update({
                tooltip:{
                    valueSuffix:"  "+label,
                }
            });

Comment: @Abbas How to remove 'x: value' from the default tooltip ?